# Create list of dict from GroupBy Frame Pandas: Python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a Data Frame Like the following:

```
Year    Month   S_ID    Channel_Name    Interaction Doc_ID  Feed_ID
2018    2       67      WhiteCoats      1           152     5776
2018    2       67      WhiteCoats      4           152     5776
2018    2       67      WhiteCoats      4           152     6046
2018    2       67      Beats           4           152     6117
2018    2       84      Beats           4           27261   6286
2018    2       84      Beats           1           9887    6286
```

**I have grouped the data with the columns:**
Year,Month,S_ID,Channel_Name,Interaction

code:

```
df.groupby(['Year','Month',S_ID,Channel_Name,Interaction])
```

but i want a new column with list of dict the column **Doc_ID,Feed_ID**

Result Frame Should Look Like:

```
Year    Month   S_ID    Channel_Name    Interaction Dictionary
2018    2       67      WhiteCoats      1           [{'Doc_id':152,'Feed_ID':5776}]
2018    2       67      WhiteCoats      4           [{'Doc_id':152,'Feed_ID':5776}]
2018    2       67      Beats           4           [{'Doc_id':152,'Feed_ID':6117}]
2018    2       84      Beats           4           [{'Doc_id':27261,'Feed_ID':6286},{'Doc_id':9887,'Feed_ID':6286}]
```

Presently i am able to create only a list:

```
df.groupby(['Year','Month',S_ID,Channel_Name,Interaction])[['Doc_id','Feed_id']].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
```

But how to Create a list of Dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to dictionary in lambda function by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Year','Month','S_ID','Channel_Name','Interaction'])['Doc_ID','Feed_ID']
         .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
         .reset_index(name='Dictionary'))
print (df1)

0  2018      2    67        Beats            4   
1  2018      2    67   WhiteCoats            1   
2  2018      2    67   WhiteCoats            4   
3  2018      2    84        Beats            1   
4  2018      2    84        Beats            4   

                                          Dictionary  
0                 [{'Doc_ID': 152, 'Feed_ID': 6117}]  
1                 [{'Doc_ID': 152, 'Feed_ID': 5776}]  
2  [{'Doc_ID': 152, 'Feed_ID': 5776}, {'Doc_ID': ...  
3                [{'Doc_ID': 9887, 'Feed_ID': 6286}]  
4               [{'Doc_ID': 27261, 'Feed_ID': 6286}]
```

Comment: Works fine.Thanks a lot

Comment: the data in the dict is numpy.64, is there any way to change it to python int data type

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar - There are changed types? What is `print (df[['Doc_ID','Feed_ID']].dtypes)` ?

Comment: doc_id - int64, feed_id-int64
;dtypes: int64(2)

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar - so there is format with `e` ? `x.to_dict('r')` changed types? Not sure if understand.

Comment: for col in articleFeedInteractionTypeCount:
    print(col)
    print(type(articleFeedInteractionTypeCount.loc[0, col])) if i run this code, doc_id and feed_id value is numpy.64

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar - Not so yeasy, because pandas maintance types internally. Possible solution is `df[['Doc_ID','Feed_ID']] = df[['Doc_ID','Feed_ID']].astype(int)`, but not always working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186459/discussion-between-sriram-arvind-lakshmanakumar-and-jezrael).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved my time.